# Dynamic combo box issues with access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on this database in Access.

Here is how the table is:
[image]

in this table the conversion fromid and toid has to match that's why I have it structured like this. That is if I select MT, then I can only convert to another MT or ST. if I select ST in the base column then I can convert to another ST or MT.

I created this form below. it has 2 combo box. the second combo box is limited based on the selection from the first combo box. That is If I select MT in the first combo, then the only options available in the second combo box is MT or ST. If I select KG then combo box 2 is limited to another KG or LB.

[image]

but the problem is that, If I select one from the combo box 1, the matching pairs are not showing. that is if I select MT it doesn't limit to MT or ST, but show two other values like L and GLL.

I have attached a copy of the database.
[Here is the link to the database I am testing with](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmHyJPlVM3nVg7x-6IB-q8gP0kKFHg)

Below is the snapshots of the code for each:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of how you achieved this, without sharing the entire database. Downloading access files is a security risk I'd like to avoid whenever possible.

Comment: I updated it with the new information

Comment: You're changing the order of columns in Combo2 in your VBA. This is likely the cause of your error. Also, you're requerying Combo0, not Combo2 in that code

Answer (score 0):

Your ID System with fromID to TOID does not seem to make any sense to me. First of all the pair is always the same. What is the intended benefit of this?

Alternative, just use the Text columns of *Base* and *To* instead and ajust properties of combo0:

Row Source: SELECT DISTINCT base FROM tblconversions;

Bound Column: 1

And the After Update method

```
Private Sub Combo0_afterUpdate()
    Dim stoSource As String

    stoSource = "SELECT DISTINCT tblconversions.To FROM tblconversions WHERE tblconversions.to = '" & Me.Combo0.Value & "'"

    Me.Combo2.RowSource = stoSource
    Me.Combo2.Requery
End Sub
```